# Updating resource-files in multiple languages ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, resx

I have a bunch of of ASP.Net pages, which I need to localize into Danish and English. I took over the project, and for some pages the `ascx.resx` and `ascx.da.resx` files already exists. Some controls have been added since the resource file was created.
I can update the standard resource file (`XXXX.ascx.resx`) with the missing entries, by "Tools"- -> "Generate Local Resources" (Using Visual Studio 2010).

But, and here comes my question, How can I update the `ascx.da.resx`?

Comment: It should be updated automatically. Modify the Danish text by opening the file and editing the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Resharper` and select `option Generate Ressource`

Link : http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html